# Tuple is not callable (IDLE Python)

Tags: python

I am currently working on a project that displays a menu, then allows you to order and gives you a receipt. My items are in a list of tuples, and the tuples contain the name of the item, the price and the calories.

My menu function(below), always gives me an error about the tuples not being "callable." How can I fix this?

```
def menu():
    order = ''
    while order != 'stop':
        print('Welcome to Peter\'s resturant! Here are the items you can order: ')
        for a, b, c in items:
            print('{:.<20} ${:2.2f} {24:28}'.format(a, b, c))
```

menu()

Thanks.

Comment: What's the exact error with trace? And show a [mcve]

Comment: What is `items`?

Comment: Items is the list containing the items you can order.

Comment: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable is the error message

Comment: Include a specific value of `items` that produces the error, and provide the *exact* traceback that you get.

Answer (score 0):

The sample of code that you have provided is not the source of your error. Rather, somewhere else in you code, you attempting to use a variable that holds a tuple as though it were a function.

Assuming that `menu` is indeed related to this problem, I can think of two likely possibilities.

1. You are accidentally reassigning the presumably global variable `menu` to a different object. Such a situation might resemble the following

   ```
   def menu():
       # ...
       pass

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       menu = (1,2,3)
       menu()
   ```

   Note that after the statement `menu = (1,2,3)`, `menu` references the tuple `(1,2,3)`, not the previously defined function.
2. You shadow the function `menu` with a local variable. This scenario might resemble the following

   ```
   def menu():
       # ...
       pass

   def foo():
       menu = (1,2,3)
       menu()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       foo()
   ```

   Note that the function `foo` creates a local variable called `menu` that "shadows" the global variable by the same name.